# macOS: What Accessibility Protocol for small array of text, checkboxes

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility

My macOS (10.10 or later) app contains a custom control containing an array of typically 2-12 rows.  Each row contains a name and two checkboxes.

Which accessibility protocol should this control implement?  I'm trying NSAccessibilityTable, but it looks like that's going to require "faking" several method implementations, because it's not really a table.  Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was due to the fact that my custom control inherited from NSControl.  VoiceOver does not know how to handle a control inside of a control, and this is not a good design pattern anyhow.  Changing the superclass to NSView caused the default behavior to *just work*.  So, the answer to my question *which protocol* is: *none*.

A related testing tip which I could not find in the [VoiceOver Getting Started Guide](https://help.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/):  When you have a view with subviews like this, if you set the `accessibilityElement` property of a subview to `YES/true`, you create an accessibility hierarchy.  If you then test with [QuickNav](https://help.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/10.12/#/vo27943), the arrow keys only get you around within the current subview.  To navigate up or down in your accessibility hierarchy, use shift-control-option upArrow or downArrow.